# How can I rewrite a SQL query without any sub-queries?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, database-design, relational-database

How can I rewrite this query without using any subqueries in SQL?
I'm not too familiar with how to do this, but I think it's done by using "join."

```
SELECT title
FROM Movies Old
Where year < ANY
  (SELECT year
  FROM Movies
  WHERE title = Old. title
  );
```

(Note: this comes from the relation Movies(title, year, length, genre, studioName, producerC#))

Comment: @philipxy this query finds movie titles that appear more than once. that's what I want. And I want to rewrite it without subqueries.

Comment: This returns a row for a title a # of times that is an obscure function of when it appears in Movies. Unless you haven't said you assume that if a title appears more than once in Movies then it's with with different years; then it returns a row per 1 minus the # of years a given title appears with. But "find movie titles that appear more than once" is an unclear description of that. Moreover it would normally be taken to mean DISTINCT titles. So ok, we can give an equivalent subquery-free query. But it's reasonable to ask in helping you, is that result really what you want?

Answer (score 2):

To literally rewrite your current query using joins you can try this:

```
SELECT m1.title
FROM Movies m1
INNER JOIN Movies m2
    ON m1.title = m2.title AND
       m1.year < m2.year
```

But if all you really want is to find movie titles which appear more than once, then when not just use a `GROUP BY` query:

```
SELECT title
FROM Movies
GROUP BY title
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```